# Unknown conflicting types

Tags: c

I'm working on this code and im getting conflicting types on several functions, which i pass pointers to some structures as parameters, and i can't see whats wrong, for example, in a function a set:

```
cliente *aux = f->inicio;
```

where cliente is a structure, but when i call it in another function with as:

```
tratar_doc(aux);
```

where the signature of it is:

```
void tratar_doc(cliente *c)
```

I get this warning: conflicting types for 'tratar_doc' [enabled by default]|

Even though my function takes a pointer of the type cliente and what im passing as an argument is a pointer of the type cliente.

Edit: Here is a code to reproduce the problem, the simplest i could get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct documento{
    int chave;
    char nome[50];
    struct documento *prox;
}documento;

typedef struct cliente{
    int conta;
    char nome[50];
    char tipo;
    struct pilha *doc;
    struct cliente *prox;
}cliente;

typedef struct fila{
    int tamanho_fila;
    struct cliente *inicio;
    struct cliente *fim;
}fila;

typedef struct pilha{
    int tamanho_doc;
    struct documento *primeiro;
    struct documento *ultimo;
}pilha;

void atender(fila *f){
    cliente *aux = f->inicio;
    cliente *aux2 = f->fim;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < ((f->tamanho_fila) - 1); i++){
        aux2 = aux2->prox;
    }
    f->inicio = aux2;
    tratar_doc(aux);
    free(aux);
}

void tratar_doc(cliente *c){
    pilha *aux = c->doc;
}
```

Ther warning: conflicting types for 'tratar_doc' [enabled by default]|

Comment: There isn't enough information in the post to diagnose the problem. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

This type of error can occur without a forward declaration of the function. If there is no forward declaration, the first time the compiler encounters the function, it can assign it a type. When the function is defined, this type may be in conflict of the assigned type.

Place

```
void tratar_doc(cliente *c);
```

before any other mention of the function. Often these forward declarations are placed in included header files.

Comment: It was exactly that, thanks for the reply, all the warnings are gone and the code now is almost done :)